# What does the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^n}{2^\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ converges to?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, markov-chains

Given a continuous M/M/1 Markov Chain (a queue with 1 station), the rate of arrivals is $\lambda$ and the rate of attendance is $\mu$. When a person arrives in the queue, there is a probability $p_n = 2^{-n}$ that when he will not enter the queue, where $n$ is the current size of the queue.

The exercise then asks what is the stationary distribution $\pi$ for such process, and, to prove that the probability of an arriving customer entering the queue is $\mu(1-\pi_o)/\lambda$.

I know that I can use detailed balance to obtain the following recursion to the stationary distribution regarding such Markov Chain:

$$\pi_n = \frac{\rho^n\pi_o}{2^{n-1}\cdot...\cdot 2}$$

Where $\rho = \lambda/\mu$. And since  one knows that since $\pi_i$ is a distribution, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n = 1$.

Hence, we obtain the following series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n =
\pi_o\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^n}{2^\frac{n^2-n}{2}}=1$$

My question is then, assuming that $\rho < 1$, what is the value of $\pi_o$?

For the second part of the question, what I did up until now was the following:
$$
P(\text{person arriving enters queue}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty
p_n \pi_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^n \pi_o}{2^{n}\cdot 2^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}}
$$

Don’t know how to progress from here.

Comment: Series with quadratic terms in the exponent are related to theta functions; things get complicated. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product

Comment: hmm, perhaps my professor didn’t realize this when he created the question...

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a closed form for that number.

The series is convergent for all real numbers $\rho \in \Bbb R$: you can easily check this using the root test.

Now, if you plug $\rho=1$ you have to evaluate the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{(1+ \dots + n)}}$$
which converges to the number
$$0.1 \ 01 \ 001 \ 0001 \ 00001 \ 000001 \ ...$$
represented in binary. I might be wrong, but as far as  know, there is no formula for numbers like these, this makes me think that there is no general formula for the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho^n}{2^{(1+ \dots + n)}}$$
either. This means that the best you can do is to write
$$\pi_0 = 1/ \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\rho^n}{2^{(1+ \dots + n)}} \right)$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. by the way that the question was phrased, it was implied that there would be a closed form solution. I will change the question to see if perhaps I did some blunder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

You want
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\rho^n}{2^\frac{n^2-n}{2}}
$.

This is
$f(\rho, 1/2)
$
where

$\begin{array}\\
f(r, x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^nx^\frac{n^2-n}{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (r/\sqrt{x})^n(\sqrt{x})^{n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

This is similar to
the Theta function
defined by
$\theta(z; t)
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2}p^n
$
where
$q = e^{\pi i  t}
$
and
$p = e^{2\pi i z}
$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don’t see how I continue from this point. could you elaborate?

Comment: Essentially, you could be able to write your sum in terms of Theta functions, which some systems can compute.